# (Hadith Collection) Ibn Abi Hatim

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I came across this hadith:

> Ibn Abi Hatim R.A. narrated that Ubayy bin Ka'b said the Messenger of
>   Allah SAWS said, "Allah created Adam tall, with thick hair, just as a
>   date tree with full branches. When Adam ate from the forbidden tree,
>   his cover fell off, and the first thing that appeared was his private
>   are. When he saw his private area, he ran away in Paradise and his
>   hair got caught in a tree. He tried to free himself and Ar-Rahman
>   called him, "O Adam! Are yo running away from Me?" when Adam heard the
>   words of Ar-Rahman (Allah), he said, "No, O my Lord! But I am shy."
>   [Ibn Abi Hatim 1:129]

I looked out whether Ibn Abi Hatim compiled a hadith collection but a Google search  produced nothing useful. (And the Wikipedia page, [List of hadith Collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hadith_collections), does not include it.) Is there an English source that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ibn Abu Hātim (Arabic: ابن أبو حاتم) is the son of [Abu Hatim ar-Razi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Hatim_Muhammad_ibn_Idris_al-Razi); he was a scholar of Qur'an and hadith, and authored his own Musnad and Tafsīr (the same book). However, Musnad Ibn Abi Hātim (known as *Tafsīr al-Qur'an al-Adhīm*) is not considered a hadith book; rather, it is a tafsīr one. The hadith you mentioned is in his tafsīr, Vol. 1, pp. 87-88,  and Vol. 5., pp. 1452-3, 3rd Ed. (I did not find it on pp. 129 as you mentioned in your post):

> وقال ابن أبي حاتم: حدثنا علي بن الحسن بن إشكاب، حدثنا علي بن عاصم، عن سعيد بن أبي عروبة، عن قتادة، عن الحسن، عن أبي بن كعب قال: قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم: إن الله خلق آدم رجلا طوالا كثير شعر الرأس كأنه نخلة سحوق، فلما ذاق الشجرة سقط عنه لباسه، فأول ما بدا منه عورته، فلما نظر إلى عورته جعل يشتد في الجنة، فأخذت شعره شجرة فنازعها، فناداه الرحمن عز وجل: يا آدم مني تفر . فلما سمع كلام الرحمن قال: يا رب لا، ولكن استحياء
>
> <sub>*— **NOTE**: My own translation, so treat with care:*</sub>
>
> Ibn Abi Hatim said 'Ali ibn al-Hassan ibn Ishkāb narrated through 'Ali ibn 'Āsim, through Sa'īd ibn Abi 'Arūba, through Qatāda, through Al-Hassa, through Ubai ibn Ka'b that the Prophet ﷺ said: "Allah created Adam as a tall man, with thick hair as a date tree with full branches. When Adam ate from the [forbidden] tree, his garments fell off. The first pat revealed was his his private parts. When he looked at his private parts, he ran fast in *Jannah* and his hair got tangled in a tree. He tried to free himself. Ar-Rahman called him, "O' Adam, is it from Me that you are running away?" When Adam heard the words of Ar-Rahman, he said, "O' my Lord, no, but out of shyness."

The hadith has different versions documented by [Ibn Is-hāq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Ishaq) in his *Al-Mubtada'* (Arabic:  المبتدأ والمبعث والمغازي) known otherwise as *Seerat ibn Is-hāq*, [Ibn 'Asākir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_%60Asakir) in his *Tarīkh*, [Ibn Abi ad-Dunya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Abi_al-Dunya) in *At-Tawba*, as well several others. [As-Suyūti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Suyuti) commented in his tafsīr titled *Ad-Durr Al-Manthūr* (Arabic: الدر المنثور), Vol. 1, pp. 132, that the hadith is authentic.

There is no English translation of Ibn Abi Hatim's works that I am aware of.

Comment: Ibn *Abu* Hatim sounds wrong to me. But maybe it's a question of taste.